# Split a string of number and words c#

Tags: c#, split

Hi I want to split a string separated by space and of the form  `1010 FirstName MidName LastName`  and use the integer 1010 in C# MVC4 Controller  This string will be parsed to the controller from a hidden form element

```
 var str = "1010 Firstname Midname LastName";

            string[] parts = str.Split(' ');
            if (parts != null)
            {
                int idpart = parts[0];
            }
```

I get error can not  implicitly convert type string to int
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "1010 Firstname Midname LastName";              
string[] parts = str.Split(' ');             
if (parts != null)             
{                 
    int idpart = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);
    string firstpart = parts[1];             
    string midpart = parts[2];
    string lastpart = parts[3];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried your solution, had to change the double quotes to single but I get this error  'can not implicitly convert type string to int'

Comment: Thats because you're trying to cast a string to an integer. exactly what the error says.

Comment: I think you maybe need to learn some more about the basics of C# and do some research yourself online. Google is a valuable resource for a beginner programmer.

Comment: thanks to all for coming to my rescue.  You are right and thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Split method - takes an array of separator characters  and returns an array of strings.

```
private static char[] splitArray = { ' ' };
string[] results = input.Split(splitArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The the exception is being caused by the line below:

```
int idpart = parts[0];
```

since parts[0] will be a string and you can't assign that to an int directly.

You need to tell it to parse the string into an int like this:

```
int idpart = int.Parse(parts[0]);
```

note that this will throw an exception if you pass a string that isn't in a format that the parser can turn to an integer so you will want to put some form of exception handling in or use the [int.TryParse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply cast string to an int, you have to explicitly convert by using int.Parse()

```
string str = "1010 FirstName MidName LastName";
var splits = str.Split(' ');
var number = int.Parse(splits[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Use int.TryParse().. You will not be thrown any exception.

var str = "1010 Firstname Midname LastName";

```
            var splittedData = str.Split(' ');

            if (splittedData != null && splittedData.Length > 0)
            {
                int _number;

                if (!int.TryParse(splittedData[0], out _number))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not a number");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Got this number - {0}", _number);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```